# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: java, android

1:Error:Execution failed for task `':app:compileDebugAidl'`.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl -oC:\android projects\BatterySaver\app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug -IC:\android projects\BatterySaver\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\android projects\BatterySaver\app\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\10165b4e57f66418e205d5742ddc6db035c2806c\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\154745c6bf28dc8cec28a1210e67c2136a8f7b86\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\793c1faa6135c81eb9ad18150702f0e5e18b6df1\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\09219873fd9a721e03835be866643cd14a5a3343\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\0557b7bd7d0a1971131eaf82c18302dd2f710525\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\d554cea8cfcff99b59c55b9c8b84b59a03608974\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\14c91e4bc7e29da9d16eeaf6de09834957ead976\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\42b7add12d52f4efbe9f1f0d9bc59e8fd29da51d\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\d9c3b42d33c9318a7cf37436ef896e51b93e514b\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\cb88c931fa35c7a340439ccc5a25f170d4f7d032\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\a69967b0de5e346deababb4c575aa3d71b71fbe5\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\52e40ef3ed71f66ed5dcd284a3bd9e6870e3aac8\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\89c55143b283f991c28fa941c1db8a40c2d5bdbe\output\aidl -IC:\Users\pc.android\build-cache\c425aed4a8f6404a94152f1eb24265c5249e456d\output\aidl -dC:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl3023659222478796510.d C:\android projects\BatterySaver\app\src\main\aidl\com\ahchtar\battery_saver\IBattery.aidl}

2: My gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName " "
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        //noinspection AndroidLintGradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same version API for `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion`. You also need to add a versionName instead a blank one. If you want to target API Level 16, change them to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think， you can click **Gradle console**, you will see the real reason,
I meet a problem is leak of 32bit libgcc_s.so files, log like this:

:compileDebugAidl
/opt_dev/android-sdk-linux_new/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

/opt_dev/android-sdk-linux_new/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

FAILED

/opt_dev/android-sdk-linux_new/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

/opt_dev/android-sdk-linux_new/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.

  > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

so on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, run the following command:
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1